# Rvest scrape comment count

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the comment count for each author in the home page http://www.sport.es/es/

I have tried the following but no success:

```
#install.packages
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(stringr)

# Store web url
url <- read_html("http://www.sport.es/es/")

# Comentarios
comment <- url %>%
html_nodes("p span a span.livefyre-commentcount")%>%
html_text(trim=TRUE)
comment
```

Thanks

Comment: That page is pretty inconsistent - it doesn't look like there is a reliable author/comment pair for every article.  This will create a lot of issues with scraping this info.

Comment: Also, the comments aren't pulling in your code because they are loaded dynamically with a call to livefyre.  You will need to use something like RSelenium - but my first issue still creates an insurmountable problem.